# change wordpress 404 page 200 status code to 404

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to change wordpress default 404 page status code(200 OK) to 404.
I have tried to do like this, but it is still returning 404 page with 200 Ok status.

```
add_action('template_redirect', '_custom_redirect');
function _custom_redirect() {
        global $wp_query;
        $wp_query->set_404();
        status_header(404);
        include( get_query_template( '404' ) );
        exit;
}
```

I need to do this just for Google . There are lot of old Urls that Google still indexing , but there are not existing and returning 404 not found. I think If I will return status 404 it will stop indexing (according to this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zpg1V6Kow-Y)  )

Answer (score 4):

I doubt that giving status 200 to 404 pages is WordPress' default behaviour, but would guess adding the header on top of your 404.php should do the trick,

```
<?php header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"); ?>
```

because I currently redirect my 404 with:

```
<?php header("Location: ../"); ?>
```

which could be a workaround.
GL with it!

Comment: I added `status_header(404);` in my controller.